# Inputs reciprocity METRIC <---> IMPERIAL

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a spreadsheet that will do simple conversions from inch to meters.
 I would like is to be able to enter a value and have the conversion populate in a different cell. For example:

Cell `B2` and `C2` are inch / meter cells. So if I enter a value into cell `C2` then `B2` will return the value of C2 * 39.37007874.
 Conversely if I enter a value into B2, C2 would return a value of B2 * 0.0254 overwriting C2.

Comment: You'll need to write some vba in the `Worksheet_Change()` event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this. To be place in the concerned sheet's code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("C2").Value = Range("B2").Value * 0.0254
    End If


    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C2")) Is Nothing Then
         Range("B2").Value = Range("C2").Value * 39.37007874 
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Note that I went for a Inches to Meters conversion. Since inches to metric make no sense.

Comment: That gets me well on my way. Thank you.